# What classification of aerial vehicle would a manned quadcopter or octocopter be?

Tags: terminology, faa, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

US here, if it makes a difference (w.r.t. FAA regulation, etc.).

There's a new upcoming class of aerial vehicles, similar to drones, however they are gigantic and they are **manned** -- that is, *manned* (piloted) quadcopters or [octocopters like these ones](https://newatlas.com/airspeeder-manned-multicopter-drone-racing/60385/).

I'm wondering what technical and/or legal classification(s) these types of vehicles would be considered to be. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 14 CFR 1.1:

> *Helicopter* means a rotorcraft that, for its horizontal motion, depends principally on its engine-driven rotors.
>
> *Rotorcraft* means a heavier-than-air aircraft that depends principally for its support in flight on the lift generated by one or more rotors.
>
> *Aircraft* means a device that is used or intended to be used for flight in the air.

A manned quad- or octocopter seems to fit the definition for “helicopter”, assuming you mean the kind that have no fixed wing.

Comment: Wow, that's going to have to change.  That definition seems totally inappropriate--

Comment: Yeah, right? I don't see how those things **require**/necessitate the same type of regulation as a full bore helicopter....